# Grammar analysis of "ぽくって"

Tags: grammar, て-form, gemination

Recently I heard the sentence:

> 強い、より命令**ぽくって**その人がこうもらえると思ってるものを返してほしい

when the teacher was trying to explain difference between "要望" and "要求".

I am wondering if "ぽくって" is the informal "テ形" of "っぽい" because it looks like "っぽくて".

Comment: You said you "heard" the sentence. Do you mean that the sentence above is how you heard it spoken? Could it be that it was just a slip of the tongue or something?

Comment: The sentence is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYF49LyT1WU) 6:19

Comment: It sounds like 命令っぽくて to me. If it was 命令ぽくって I think the pitch of the くwould be different.

Answer (score 9):

It is exactly as you stated.

Using 「Word + **っぽい**」 over 「Word + **ぽい**」 is actually a "recent" phonetic trend in the history of the language.  The trend is only about 100-plus years old.

If you read novels from Meiji Era (1868 - 1912), you will notice the coexistence of both forms.

「～～くって」 is the colloquial form of 「～～くて」 and it is very common in our spoken language.  It is, of course, the te-form of an i-adjective.

e.g. 「このリンゴはあまく（っ）ておいしい。」("This apple is sweet and yummy.")

It can, however, be kind of difficult (and even stressful) to utter  「命令{めいれい}っぽくって」 with two small っ sounds in such a short phrase because, as in any language, we tend to speak fast in our informal conversations.

Thus, uttering either 「命令ぽくって」or 「命令っぽくて」 using only one small っ would be much easier.

I think this is why the person in question said 「命令ぽくって」 (almost) instinctively as a native speaker.