# Adjective-i +くって usage

Tags: word-usage

I have been struggling on finding out what is the meaning of this sentence:

> 嬉しくって 楽しくって 冒険も いろいろしたね

Especially in this part

> 嬉しくって 楽しくって

I know that those are adjective-i. But I do not understand how it is conjugated into that phrase. Please explain me how it is conjugated and what does it mean then. Thank you.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29006/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53467/9831